# Как минимизировать javascript со вставками PHP с среде PHPStorm

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm

У нас самописный PHP framework.
Страницы на фронтенде генерируются из PHP темплейтов на лету.
В некоторых PHP темлпейтах есть довольно большие JS скрипты, которые хотелось бы минимизировать (uglifyjs).
Но js скрипты не чистые, а со вставкой в них php кода, к примеру вот так:

```
<script> var lat = <?= $lat ?></script>
```

Такой код uglifyjs не принимает и выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: Unexpected token: operator «<»

Есть ли возможность как-то дать понять uglifyjs что в js есть вставки PHP кода и что их нужно игнорировать (оставлять как есть)?

Comment: Такая возможность у uglifyJS отсутствует.

Comment: При таком подходе у вас и кеширование не работает. Можете попробовать написать свой минимизатор )

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko кеширование у нас как раз работает - но оно на уровень выше - на уровне CloudFlare.

Comment: Очень интересно, как работает кеширование в случае, если в скрипте есть `<script> var lat = <?= $lat ?></script>` и значения `$lat` будут разными?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko значение $lat меняется от страницы к странице, страниц миллионы (страница адреса)

Comment: И каждая страница с этим значением кешируется? То есть у вас закешированно миллион страниц, отличающихся одним значением? о_О

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko закешированно намного больше, я показывал $lat только для примера, там много чего отличается - вопрос был не в том что отличается :)